# How can i build MAUI projects ? Target Framework Error NU1012

Tags: .net, maui

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net8.0-android, net8.0-ios, net8.0-maccatalyst   MauiApp1    C:\Workspace\Software\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj 1`

I can see that you've tried various solutions to resolve the issue with compiling MAUI projects, but you're still encountering errors. Below is your text translated into English:

"I can't compile MAUI projects. I've put the error image below, you can check it. I think I've tried every possible solution.

[image: error screen]

Some of the solutions I've tried:

- Updated Visual Studio
- Removed and reinstalled MAUI package
- Updated Visual Studio to pre-release version
- Tried .NET 7
- Tried .NET 8
- Tried various versions such as .NET 8.0.101, .NET 8.0.100-rc.2
- Tried downloading from NuGet packages using VPN
- Repaired Visual Studio
- Tried downloading with the command "dotnet workload install [package name]" (macOS, MAUI-Windows)
- Uninstalled and reinstalled SDKs from Visual Studio Installer
- Created new projects continuously"

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update your visual studio to the latest one and try again.

There is a similar issue about this problem, you can check it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5778).

You can also try the workaround included in above link.

To fix existing project you can try:

1.reset all visual studio settings.

2.delete all `.vs` folders.

3.delete all `.user` folder.